# Methods depending on each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, billing

I'm building a complex billing system with Ruby on Rails. I have an `Invoice` model that has many items and payments. The invoice is considered paid when the `paid_cents` are greater than or equal to the `total_cents`.

Everything worked fine until I added support for late fees. Obviously, these fees should only be calculated when the invoice hasn't been paid. For instance, if the invoice was due on 2014-01-01, it has been paid on  2014-01-05 and today is 2014-01-24, the fees should be calculated for 4 days only.

In order to accomplish that, I added a check to the `late_days` method, making it return 0 if `paid_cents` was greater than or equal to `total_cents` AND the last payment was delivered before the invoice's due date.

Here's the issue: the `total_cents` are calculated summing the items' amounts and the late fees. In turn, the `late_fee_cents` method calls `late_days` which relies on `total_cents` to check whether the invoice has been paid.

This results in an infinite loop where the methods will call each other till the end of time (or someone pulls the plug).

Here's some code from my model:

```
def daily_late_fee_percentage
  return 0 unless late_fee_percentage && late_fee_interval
  late_fee_percentage.to_f / late_fee_interval.to_f
end

def daily_late_fee_cents
  incomplete_total_cents.to_f / 100.0 * daily_late_fee_percentage
end

def late_days
  return 0 unless due_at

  days = Date.today - due_at
  days = 0 if days < 0

  days.to_i
end

def late_fee_cents
  daily_late_fee_cents * late_days
end

def total_cents
  incomplete_total_cents + late_fee_cents
end
```

I feel like I'm completely missing something obvious.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: late_days -> total_cents -> late_fee_cents ->late_days ... infinite

Comment: I'd look at extracting the `late_days` functionality into another method completely. Perhaps into a rake task which runs each night? I can write an answer if you want

Comment: @RichPeck: I'd rather calculate the fee dynamically than change the amount every night.

Answer (score 1):

How should `late_fee_cents` be calculated? Is it only a fraction of the invoice's initial "total cents" excluding "late fees" multiplied by the days the invoice is overdue, or is it a fraction of the initial total cents plus late fees multiplied by the days the invoice is overdue?

If the former is true, then this might work:

We can define `total_cents` like this:

```
def total_cents(include_late_fees = true)
    include_late_fees ? incomplete_total_cents + late_fee_cents : incomplete_total_cents
end
```

And `late_days` like this:

```
def late_days
  return 0 unless due_at
  return 0 if paid_cents >= total_cents(false) && (payments.last.try(:delivered_at) || due_at) <= due_at

  days = Date.today - due_at
  days = 0 if days < 0

  days.to_i
end
```

*Note that in `late_days` we are using `total_cents(false)`.*

This should eliminate the infitie loop.

If the latter is true, then first write down the exact mathematical formula for calculating the total invoice fee, including late fees and make sure
it doesn't have infinite recursion. The formula might contain sigma (Σ) or [(Π)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) expressions.

Then it should be easy to convert it to code.

#### EDIT:

I think what you are trying to achieve is basically charging an interest on the debt (overdue fee). This is similar to computing [compound interest](http://math.about.com/library/weekly/aa042002a.htm).

Comment: The fee is calculated on the original total amount. However, the invoice is considered paid when the user has paid the original amount PLUS the accumulated fee. I have added some code to the question.